# Constructor function not working?? P5.JS

Tags: javascript, p5.js

So I'm trying to figure out why it says display() is not a function, I feel this is code could be completely wrong...

Also, I'm kind of confused about the x and y position of the image? Where do I define them.

The purpose of this code is for a Stormtrooper png to be floating around the screen, I eventually want him to make sounds when clicked, and for him to rotate(which I'm also stumped on) - a live version can be seen here: https://benjamingibbsportfolio.000webhostapp.com/ (it's my semi-finished portfolio, plz don't be harsh)

I've done this code correctly a different way, I'm just learning about constructor functions atm. I was initially excited as I thought I'd finally got a hold of the 'this' keyword, then it all came crashing down!

```
function preload() {

img = loadImage("stormy3.png");

}

function storm(x,y,xSpeed,ySpeed,img) {
 this.x = x;
 this.y = y;
 this.xSpeed = xSpeed;
 this.ySpeed = ySpeed;
 this.img = img;

 this.display = function() {
  image(this.img,this.x,this.y);
}

this.move = function() {
  this.x = this.x + this.xSpeed;
  this.y = this.y + this.ySpeed;
}
this.bounce = function() {
  if(this.x > width || this.x < 0) {
    this.xSpeed = this.xSpeed * -1;
  }
  if(this.y > height || this.y < 0) {
    this.ySpeed = this.ySpeed * -1;
  }
}
}

function setup() {
 // TRANSPARENT BACKGROUND*
  background(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
//
var myCanvas = createCanvas(1440, 4000);
myCanvas.position(0, 0);
}

function draw() {
 // TRANSPARENT BACKGROUND*
 clear();
 //
 storm.display();
 storm.move();
 storm.bounce();
}
```

Comment: How are you constructing `storm`?  Have you tried new Storm(...)

Comment: Show us where `storm` is defined

Comment: Yeah I've completely messed this up tbh, it doesnt make any sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've created a constructor function called `storm`, which defines a **type** called `storm`. But you haven't create an **instance** of that type.

Now, when you do this:

```
storm.display();
storm.move();
storm.bounce();
```

The `storm` in this code is referencing the **type**, not a particular instance. That's why you're getting an error. You can't call functions using the type like this, you have to go through an instance.

To create an instance, you should use the **`new`** keyword:

var myStorm = new storm(100, 200 1, 2, yourImageHere);

Then you could use that instance to call your functions:

```
myStorm.display();
myStorm.move();
myStorm.bounce();
```

A couple of random notes: your constructor function should really start with an upper-case letter, that way it's easier to tell the difference between types and variables holding instances. Also, you aren't ever defining your `img` variable, so that's going to give you problems.

Shameless self-promotion: I've written a tutorial about constructor functions available [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/javascript/creating-objects).

Comment: Amazing thanks for the in-depth answer, I've printed that tutorial off to read as well. Thanks!!